# Strange characters in PHP echo resulting in invalid JSON

Tags: php, json, character

I am using echo in php to return a database request. When trying to decode the result in Flash I get errors telling me of unexpected characters. When I looked at the output in the browser it looked fine. But when I copied the contents (Select All -> Copy) and then ran the text through a script in php I saw a lot of strange characters. This explains why the JSON decoding fails, but how do I get rid of the strange characters?

**Test script to check the string**

```
    $string = str_split($string);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($string);
    echo '<pre>';
```

Result:

```
    [0] => ï
        [1] => »
        [2] => ¿
        [3] => ï
        [4] => »
        [5] => ¿
        [6] => ï
        [7] => »
        [8] => ¿
...
```

Comment: ï»¿ is the [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which is set by text editors to hint other editors that the text uses UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII, ISO-8859-1 etc. How exactly did you "ran the text through a script" after you copied it? Could you please specifiy exactly in which order you did what because I think that is where the problem lies.

Comment: I copied the output in the browser and pasted it into a variable ($string) in my test php file. The characters is not visual but when I try to step through the characters in the editor I get a hint that they are there. After running the script (showed in my question) I can see the characters.

Comment: In your first step (where you use `echo` to return the database request) can you please use something like `file_put_contents('out.txt', $output);` to write the exact output you sent to the browser into a file, upload it somewhere and put a link to it in here? By copying it from your browser and inserting it into your PHP-Editor-Of-Choice the text may have been converted, prefixed (with BOM) etc. and thus can't be used as a base to find the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11261669/473841). The problem was that my PHP files were saved with UTF-8 encoding with BOM. Saving the files with UTF-8 encoding solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the server is replying with the correct content-type header:

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```