# Parsing json with jquery wont working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I run `json_encode` PHP function and get following output:

```
[{"id":"1","size":"124","name":"Team1","picture":1},
{"id":"5","size":"76","name":"Team 4","picture":2},
{"id":"3","size":"25","name":"Team2","picture":3},
{"id":"4","size":"17","name":"Team3","picture":4}]
```

Now I want to parse it using JQUERY and add it to my web page. I run following script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#myButton2').click(function(e) {
        $.get("http://localhost:99/result/getBestOne", function(data) {
        alert(data+"");
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(obj+"");

       });
    });
});

</script>
```

My problem is that first alert is working, but in second one, I get error:`**Ucought SyntaxError: Unexpected Token**`

Where is the problem?

Comment: Try using the console, that way you don't have to hack it together with adding strings and other weirdness ?

Comment: The JSON is invalid as others have pointed out. Try to validate your JSON the next time, using [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/) for example.

Comment: How that can happen when I use php function?

Comment: There is no problem with JSON format, person who edited my question deleted my original JSON string

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that it is not valid JSON..The starting braces for last 2 objects are missing..

```
{"id":"1","size":"124","name":"Team1","picture":1},
{"id":"5","size":"76","name":"Team 4","picture":2},
{"id":"3","size":"25","name":"Team2","picture":3},
{"id":"4","size":"17","name":"Team3","picture":4}
```

Comment: Person who edited my question, deleted my braces!

Answer (score 1):

where is the open braces "{" for those 2 lines?

> "id":"3","size":"25","name":"Team2","picture":3},
>
> "id":"4","size":"17","name":"Team3","picture":4}

Comment: Person who edited my question, deleted my braces!

Comment: Try to use console.log instead alert, and copy paste the reponse here

Comment: Here is what I get in console:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  all.js:16
m.extend.parseJSON all.js:16
(anonymous function) localhost:177
r all.js:17
E.onreadystatechange

Comment: maybe this one can help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: MOZILLA FIREFOX CONSOLE: I have two uknown signs ÿÿ
Timestamp: 24.2.2013 21:58:39
Error: uncaught exception: Invalid JSON: ÿÿ[{"id":"1","kolicina":"124","nazivTima":"Team1","picture":1},{"id":"5","kolicina":"76","nazivTima":"Team 4","picture":2},{"id":"3","kolicina":"25","nazivTima":"Team2","picture":3},{"id":"4","kolicina":"17","nazivTima":"Team3","picture":4}]

Comment: then check the server side script, maybe you're file returns not only json string?
and also please check, php file encoding too

Comment: My server side script is following: <?php echo print_r(json_encode($najboljiTimovi));?>. No spaces, no new lines, encoding is UTF without BOM

Comment: I think problem is with your php file encoding, please check this url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261489/php-include-files-are-making-json-data-invalid/11261669#11261669

Comment: Jes, there was ENTER in my controler php file, and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The text you are trying to parse is not valid JSON, therefore you are getting a syntax error.

If you are not sure what is wrong, I recommend copy-and-pasting your JSON code into this website:

http://jsonlint.com/